# Dropdown menu behind content

Tags: html, css

if you take a look at this [website](http://cpureus.com/medianeeds/) and you find the word "TIPUS D'IMMOBLES" at the center of the page, in the form, you can see that if you click it, it will show a dropdown menu but it gets cut by the bottom content. I tried with z-index but i cant manage to show the full menu.

Any ideas? Thank you all.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: And also you are not supposed to use `span` as direct child of `ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styles include:

```
section {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 80px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The issue is caused by this rule's `overflow: hidden;`. To fix it, you could set `overflow: visible` on the `section` containing the form as in:

```
<section role="home-slide" class="slideshow home" style="overflow:visible;">
```